# How to Read contacts in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

I am a beginner in Xamarin Platform, & trying to read contacts in xamarin forms. Even tried using Xamarin.Mobile, But it gives lots of error. Found 1 more plugin i.e. Xamarin.contacts https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Contacts
but no relevant example is given. Please help with a relevant example using Xamarin.contacts for all 3 platforms
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. What kind of error is Xamarin.Mobile producing? Could you show us some of the code you're having trouble with with Xamarin.Contacts?

Comment: There is an example at github `List<Contact> contacts = null; CrossContacts.Current.PreferContactAggregation = false;//recommended contacts = CrossContacts.Current.Contacts
            .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.LastName) && c.Phones.Count > 0)         
            .ToList();` dont forget to set persmissions Android: `android.permissions.READ_CONTACTS permission is required`

Comment: Actualy i wanted to display all the contacts in a list, and not understanding where to add this code?? do i need to add it in PCL??

Comment: @ Will : Hi & Thanks for ur reply. well using Xamarin.Mobile is not Supporting ios, and not displaying anything on screen and same for android too. And about Xamarin.Contact i dnt have idea where i exactly need to add the given stuff

Comment: Have a look at Xamarin.Essentials

Answer (score 3):

Just keep in mind Xam.Plugin.Contacts is currently in alpha version.

This is my implementation. Notice despite of class names, it is not a real MVVM pattern. I simplified the code as much as I could to help readability.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Contacts" 
         x:Class="Contacts.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{ Binding Contacts }">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{ Binding DisplayName }" 
                      Detail="{ Binding Nickname }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>    
</ContentPage>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Plugin.Contacts.Abstractions.Contact> Contacts { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Plugin.Contacts.Abstractions.Contact>();
        ReloadContacts();
    }

    public void ReloadContacts()
    {
        // Device may request user permission to get contacts access.
        var hasPermission = CrossContacts.Current.RequestPermission()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();

        if (hasPermission)
        {
            this.Contacts.Clear();

            List<Plugin.Contacts.Abstractions.Contact> contacts = null;
            CrossContacts.Current.PreferContactAggregation = false;

            if (CrossContacts.Current.Contacts == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            contacts = CrossContacts.Current.Contacts.ToList();
            foreach (var contact in contacts)
            {
                this.Contacts.Add(contact);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: Xam.Plugin.Contacts is not longer in development.... `THIS PLUGIN IS NOT UNDER DEVELOPMENT AND NOT SUPPORTED` : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin Of course you can always fork the repo and use it as a base in your apps... ;-)